# How to Create a Paytm Checksum on firebase Server for android app?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, google-cloud-firestore, checksum, paytm

I don't have any server where I can run PHP code for checksum . So is there any way I can do the checksum work on Firebase Server ?? If so please tell me code or the procedure . I need a Paytm gateway for my android app .

Comment: did you found any solution? can you help me , i am also facing the same issue.